# SQL date settings

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Just as example
I have this easy view on my sql database

```
    SELECT     NOME
    FROM         dbo.PROMO
    WHERE     (VAL_DA < '28/02/2017 10:15:44')
```

it works
Then I make a backup and restore the db on another server

I run the same view and get the error
sql the conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out of range datetime
I need ot make the change day - month to have it work

```
    SELECT     NOME
    FROM         dbo.PROMO
    WHERE     (VAL_DA < '02/28/2017 10:15:44')
```

Language in Server properties is English in both.
I controlled all settings between the 2 servers and look the same.
Is there Any other setting I should look for?
Any suggestion?

Comment: There are some settings to tweak but it would be better to get into the habit of using unambiguous strings (e.g. `'2017-02-28T10:15:44'`) or to perform *explicit* conversions from strings to `datetime`s where you specify the *style* parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Every Login for the database can override the Default server language.

ie While creating Login for the DB we can explicitly set the default Language for the Login. eg us_english, uk_english etc.

so no matter what the server language is, The Login used for attaching database clearly had different language settings than the Login used to take backup.

```
 SELECT language FROM syslogins
```

Probably the language for both the Source and Destination  Database is different.

In your case the Source Db's Login had language `uk_english` but the destination db's Login had `Us_english`.

**To preserve the date-format, you need the destination DB's login language configured same as the source DB's Login.**

Comment: Thanks Shekhar this solved, you were wonderful, I know I can use different formats to go over languages but here codes are already written I just needed to change the server. Thanks again.

Comment: @lucullo08 Kudos!!. mark the answer as an answer if it had helped :)

Comment: God I don't know how please advise